# ZMQ in Python2.5

Tags: python, zeromq, python-2.5, pyzmq

I need to install zmq in Python2.5.
In github they say that the last version that supports Python2.5 is: pyzmq 2.1.11. From here they have removed the support. On their releases page [Downloads](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/downloads), they have several installers but not for Python2.5. Therefore I have downloaded the version 2.1.11 and I have tried with:

```
python setup.py install
```

But gives me the following error:
Warning:

```
Could not copy libzmq into zmq/, which is usually necessary on
Windows.Please specify zmq prefix via configure --zmq=/path/to/zmq or copy
libzmq into zmq/ manually.
Configure: Autodetecting ZMQ settings...
Custom ZMQ dir:       C:\Users\puig\Documents\zmq\libzmq\tests
error: MSVCCompiler instance has no attribute '_MSVCCompiler__root'
Fatal:
Failed to build or run ZMQ test program.  Please check to make sure:

* You have a C compiler installed
* A development version of Python is installed (including header files)
* A development version of ZMQ >= 2.1.4 is installed (including header files)
* If ZMQ is not in a default location, supply the argument --zmq=<path>
* If you did recently install ZMQ to a default location,
  try rebuilding the ld cache with `sudo ldconfig`
  or specify zmq's location with `--zmq=/usr/local`
```

I have tried to download libzmq, and have specified the path:

```
python setup.py configure --zmq=/path/libzmq
```

But it does not work, I'm not understanding the difference between libzmq and pyzmq. And I do not know where to find libzmq.dll and where to copy it

Thanks!

Comment: Windows x64. Sorry

Comment: Do you have a c compiler installed? Msvc? Perhaps you wil be able to download it prebuilt.

Comment: No! This could be ok? (https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=14632)

Comment: no thats no good. It's for programs already compiled.

Comment: Installed MinGW, but still the same error